# Получить id конференции

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь получить id конференции, с которой был написан репорт. Но мне постоянно возвращает в тексте "1", для любой конференции.

```js
{
        regexp: /^\/rep ([^]+)/i,
        f: function(params, msg) {
   vk.api.messages.send({
                    user_id: 152408885,
                    message: "&#128235; Репорт из конференции: " + vk.api.messages.getChat({
                     chat_id: msg.chat_id,
                    }) + '. ' + params[1],
                });
    msg.send("&#128228; Ваш вопрос успешно отправлен! \n\n&#128219; Среднее время ожидания ответа: 5 минут.")   
        },
        user: user,
        description: "/rep - ваш репорт"
    }
```

Comment: Вопрос, собственно, сводится к фильтрованию текста с помощью regex?

Comment: Нет. ПРи помощи этой команды я должен оправить текст пользователю и получить id конференции все.
Возможно есть пример как получит id при помощи команды на js?